# tkinter calling grandparents instance variable from a separate class with error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, parent-child, instance-variables, super

How can I access instance variable "self.data = 42" from "class Day"?

This is the simplest form of my larger GUI program, so please ignore the window that is popping up.  I am working on the data logic of it, and I don't know how to access this variable.

What I need is to be able to print ( f"from class Day {self.parent.data}"), the the error says "AttributeError: 'Week' object has no attribute 'data'", which is logical because "class Day" is a composition of "class Week" (this is designed for my GUI set up "has a" relationship).

I had tried creating another instance "self.day1 = Day(self)", that didn't work.  I had also tried to "class Day(tk.Frame, Application):" to see if I can inherit the data, but still has the same error.

If someone can help me to make this work this will allow me to understand super()/composition better.

Thanks again for your assistance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = 42

        self.week1 = Week(self)


class Week(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.day1 = Day(self)

        print ( f"from class Week {self.parent.data}")

class Day(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

#        print ( f"from class Day {self.parent.data}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().mainloop()
```

Comment: `Day`s `parent` is a `Week`.  `Week`s `parent` is an `Application`.  `Application` has `data`.  So, from an instance of `Day`, `self.parent.parent.data`.

Comment: @jasonharper,  thank you for your quick response.  Looking at the solution, I feel so stupid...haha.  is there a "prettier" solution?